# MySql Count clause with where

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the number of 'Shipped' orders with an amount greater than 1000 from two tables.

I have table Orders(Status column) and table Payments(Amount column)

```
select count(o.status, p.amount)
from orders o, payments p
where (o.status = 'Shipped' AND p.amount>1000);
```

After getting an error I broke up the problem into two with the first finding all 'Shipped' status in Orders. This works just fine.

```
select count(o.status)
from orders o 
where o.status = 'Shipped';
```

But trying to count all payments above 1000 doesn't seem to work.

```
select count(p.amount)
from payments p 
where p.amount>=1000;
```

In case anyone needs the file, I am using the sample DB from MySQl sample database 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work," mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: "You have an error in your mysql syntax please consult the manual..." not a very helpful error message.

Comment: Does `select count() as cnt from payments where amount >= 1000;` work?

Comment: your table seems not related ..  you have not condtion for join the orders  table to the payments table  ..

Answer (score 1):

if you want know the number of order "shipped" with payment with (each) amount > 1000 the first you should join the table in proper way
looking to your schema the order table is realated to payments table via the customers on customerNumber

so you should

```
  select count(distinct o.id)
  from orders o
  INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customerNumber =  o.customerNumber
  INNER JOIN  payments p p.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
  where o.status = 'Shipped' 
  AND p.amount>1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, table above doesn't work but I worked something out with inner join.

Comment: what do you mean  wih "table above doesn't work "  ..  you have an error .. show me the exact error message  ... wrong result  ..  update your question add  a clear data sample as tabular tex (not a link to a tutorial)   and your expected  result